# Is it possible to pre-fill a checkbox field using URL parameters? Fields are from CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, drupal-7

Looking for tips on how to pre-select a checkbox (or anything besides a textfield) in a webform using URL parameters. We have pre-filled a textfield with URL params. We also found [this article](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246743/how-can-i-set-a-webforms-field-value-by-query-parameter) that explains how to pre-select a field created in webforms. The problem we have is pre-selecting a field brought in from CiviCRM. Does anyone have any tips or know of other nodes that will enable this? We are running Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.41.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this via two different methods.

One method is using a 'pass-thru' field. I create a webform only text field (it does not need to exist in CiviCRM custom data) and have it pre-fill based on a URL parameter. Then I use conditionals to say if that text field equals "X" set this CiviCRM select field to "X". (I hide this field on the front-side of the form.)

The other method is jquery. You can load a javascript file through a custom module (or I've also used the Javascript injector https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector). In jQuery you can get the URL parameters and then in some if statements adjust the value/property of fields on the form. Happy to expound if you need.

Comment: concur we have done via having a textfield (webform component) set via the URL and then the checkbox (civi field) set via conditionals from that textfield

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since Civi Groups are treated as checkboxes in Webforms, I was hoping to add contacts to groups using this same method. I'm not having any luck using this method. Is there something different to try for adding to a group via URL parameters?

Comment: This is still possible although it might be clunkier than you'd like. You should be able to still use conditionals to say if pass-thru text field equals "staff" then Group(s) is set to the desired group ID, you can set multiple IDs using a comma. But I don't think this method will maintain any groups the contact is a part of (if you're using the groups in relation to a contact). This is why on occasion I've used some custom js - I have a little more control over appending values instead of replacing them.

Comment: I didn't think to try group IDs. We ended up having the conditional assign a tag and then used CiviRules to add them to a group based on that tag. I appreciate the follow up.